# GNU make pattern rule when .c files in different directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I can write pattern rules like that to compile `.c`files to `.o`files.

```
%.o:%.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

But it seems that this method will only work when all the c file are in the *same directory*.

If my project's struct  is like this

```
|-folder1
|----a.c
|----b.c
|-folder2
|----c.c
|----d.c
|Makefile
```

I have to change my `Makefile` to this

```
%.o:folder1/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@ 
%.o:folder2/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

If i have a lot of folders, I think repeating code like this is not the correct way to solve the problem.

Anyone has better solutions?

Comment: I've seen projects where every directory has a separate Makefile. I've not done that before, but I'd guess that the Makefile in the root directory calls those in subdirectories, which then build something and copy it into the root directory.

Comment: You seem to have your targets and prerequisites mixed up. Where do you want the object files to go?

Comment: @Beta sorry ,  the .o should be the target and the .c should be the prerequisite. I have corrected the errors in post.

Comment: Thanks for  comment. Spliting big makefile into small parts seems a better solution.

Comment: Do you have a reason you can't add `folder1` and `folder2` to your `VPATH`?  Then you wouldn't need to write an explicit `%.o: %.c` rule, as the standard inbuilt one would Just Work.